# expected ';' at end of declaration list when I have one?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, definition

so i've declared a struct which is shown below

```
struct location {
    char occupier;
    int points;
    int x;
    int y;
    int current_x = PLAYER_STARTING_COL;
    int current_y = PLAYER_STARTING_ROW;
    
};
```

I have made a struct variable called starting however, when I compile it I get an error saying it expects a semicolon at the end of my declaration list? Is there any way I can fix this? I'm a beginner to C and just need a bit of help

```
struct location starting;
```

Comment: This isn't C++. You can't specify member default values in a C struct like that.

Comment: It's not valid in C to have initialisers inside a struct.

Comment: @kaylum if i intialise it outside the struct will i still be able to change its value and modify it ?

Comment: @user16068074 Yes, unless you make the instance `const`

Answer (score 1):

In C opposite to C++ you may not initialize data members of a structure in its definition.

So you have to write

```
struct location {
    char occupier;
    int points;
    int x;
    int y;
    int current_x;
    int current_y;
    
};
```

and to initialize data members when an object of the structure type is defined as for example

```
struct location starting = 
{ 
    .current_x = PLAYER_STARTING_COL, .current_y = PLAYER_STARTING_ROW 
};
```

If the above declaration is a file scope declaration then `PLAYER_STARTING_COL` and `PLAYER_STARTING_ROW` must be constant expressions.